# Ubuntu on login don't ask password

Tags: passwords, login, ubuntu-12.04, auto-login

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I have set a password for login. It doesn't ask at startup but when I lock the screen it asks the password. How to make ubuntu to ask password at login?

Can anybody help? I have googled & checked some answers on Ask Ubuntu but it's not helping.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you checked "`Login automatically`" while you installed your ubuntu:

[image]

This might help: [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171849/498798)

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to find that setting here :
`System->Administration->Users and Groups`.

This option is provided by package gnome-system-tools, install it if necessary:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS:

1. Go to top right corner and look for Settings
2. On left menu click on Users
3. Unlock the screen with your current password
4. Then set Automatic Logic